# I keep getting 401 [No Body response] using RestTemplateBuilder

Tags: java, spring, basic-authentication, resttemplate, lombok

I have two RestTemplate Beans, however sometimes when authRestTemplate is used get a 401 error (`org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 : [no body]`) I'm not sure why this is happening since it does not happen consistently.

This is how I have configured my RestTemplate.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {

    private final FooConfig fooConfig;

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate authRestTemplate(final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder){
        return restTemplateBuilder
                .basicAuthentication(fooConfig.getUsername(), fooConfig.getPassword())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate basicRestTemplate(final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
                .build();
    }

}
```

If I am using the authRestTemplate it would look something like this

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class authSubmissionServiceImpl implements CompletedApplicationService {
    private final RestTemplate authRestTemplate;
    private final FooConfig fooConfig;

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            
             Objects.requireNonNull(
                 authRestTemplate.getForObject(
                     String.format(somePath, fooConfig.getBaseUrl()),
                     String.class)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I use constructor injection and use the same variable name as the RestTemplkete bean to differentiate between the two. Because of this, I don't need to use @Qualifier(). However, I know the authentication is being sent because 99% of the time the request goes through fine but there are spontaneous times where I get 401 [No Body] and I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated